# Flow chart generator from source files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visualization, flowchart

I'm searching for a tool that let me generate a flow chart for a given project. It is difficult understand others code by looking at code, a flow chart can be very helpful.

My Project is in VS 2010 Professional Edition.

Comment: Take a look at [Visual Studio Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx). It may have something for helping you to generate Sequence Diagram/Activity Diagram or so called "flow chart".

Comment: Get yourself Visual Paradigm for UML - it's great and is free for 30 days and you can check if it what you're looking for and decide for yourself. I bet it will suits you.

Comment: Take a look at [Code Rocket](http://www.getcoderocket.com/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The Visual Studio Learning Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/2A06FB8C-C2B1-417B-9F7D-57254D74905E) has a flowchart generator, but unfortunately, it only works with the 2008 editions.

What you probably actually want are called Sequence Diagrams. This functionality is built into VS 2010 Ultimate Edition.

You just right-click inside a method and select “Generate the sequence diagram”  from the pop up menu.
[image: sequence diagrams]

Comment: I did not find Sequence diagram in professional edition, I think it is in Ultimate edition.

Comment: Yes, it is in the UE, not Professional. In the future, it would be helpful if you specified which version you are using.

Comment: I think it is available only for C# projects and not for C++ projects.

Answer (score 5):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) has a [Call Tracking](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Call_Tracking) feature that can display incoming and outgoing calls  sequenced in an interactive, graphical tree view.

[image]

It also has a similar feature for [Value Tracking](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Value_Tracking) that displays data flows.

[image]